# Rolling own code instead of using libraries, avoiding the common approach

Tags: libraries

I have seen a plethora of projects roll their own things instead of using well tested libraries.

In some other instances I have seen people re-implement Elliptic Curves and Random Number Generators, refusing to use tested libraries, because their code is "better".

Why do people do this, choose to spend their time implementing something instead of using something that has been already done, tested and deployed in a plethora of systems?

For example, the Signal Android messenger app has the whole, full copy of OpenSSL embedded into itself for encryption. [Ref](https://github.com/WhisperSystems/Signal-Android/tree/master/jni/openssl)
Why not use BouncyCastle or `java.security.*`?

Is it a ego thing? Is it a trust thing, ie. they don't trust libraries?

Comment: There is an infinite reasons why one may want to employ their own solution opposed to an existing one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be for a host of different reasons.

Build vs. buy (or use by reference) *should* come down to a thorough analysis.  That said, many folks get into programming because they like building things.  Sometimes it's rewarding to build your own code (even when a third party library exists).

That said, I'll try to list some reasons why you might not want to use third party libraries:

- Licensing: Does the third party library licensing conflict or restrict your intended usage of your code?  For example, GPL-licensed code may not be the best pick for something used commercially.
- Security: Has the third party code been thoroughly analyzed for any security vulnerabilities?  If it's public-facing, then have there been exploits in the past that have targeted this code?  If so, then how quickly have the contributors fixed things (or have they even bothered to issue a patch).
- Ease of use: For example, I may not want to try to use a C++ library in C# code.  It's possible, but it's less straightforward than using a C# library.
- Bug fixes: Is development ongoing on the third party library?  If there's a bug, then how easily can you get it fixed?
- Domain knowledge: We can't specialize in everything.  Using your example of encryption, I'd *strongly* discourage attempting to build an encryption library from scratch unless you have an encryption background.
- Simplicity: Your use case may be much smaller than what a third party library is built to provide.  For example, if you needed to build a `Point` class to represent an X,Y,Z point, then you could reference a third party graphics library.  But if you don't need the ability to do graphics calculations on 3D space, then referencing an entire graphics library might be overkill.

All this said, there are many times using a third party library works (and is the appropriate choice).  Using your example, I'd never try to implement an encryption stack on my own -- there's no reason to do so with the plethora of open-source options available.

Comment: Oh one reason why you might want to implement your own https component is because most current versions (one chrome uses) do not support newest proposed version of TLS. Using your own which sticks more closely to the standard may not be a bad thing. Also SSL had well known vulnerabilities early on. As I commented to the question there is literally an infinite set of valid reasons why you would implement your own solution. This is a poor question which is heavily opinion based.